# Requested resource not available using Struts 2 - Tiles

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, hyperlink, tiles

I am using Struts2 + Tiles 2

I am using iterator to dynamically generate hyperlinks on my JSP page and mapping them to a single action class.

My `struts.xml` is:

```xml
<action name="actionName" method="execute"
    class="myClass">
    <result name="error"  type="tiles">/error.tiles</result>
    // some more result tags
</action>
```

and my hyperlinks are:

```jsp
<a href="/myTilesProjName/actionName?hyperlink=<s:property value="ID"/>"> 
    <s:property value="ID"/>
</a>
```

I have hyperlink declared as string in `myClass` and have getters/setters for it
and when I execute I get `404 error: requested resource ... actionName .... not available`

am I going wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links in Struts2 are generated with `<s:a>` tag. You can change your hyperlink with

```jsp
<s:a action="actionName"><s:param name="hyperlink" value="%{ID}"/><s:property value="ID"/></s:a>
```

If you know a namespace for the action, then you should also add a `namespace` attribute.

Another approach is to use `href` attribute combined with `<s:url>` tag. For example

```jsp
<s:url var="myHyperlinkUrl" action="actionName"><s:param name="hyperlink" value="%{ID}"/></s:url>
<s:a href="%{#myHyperlinkUrl}"><s:property value="ID"/></s:a>
```

In this case you can reuse the generated url via referencing its variable. Also it should properly encode the url.